# Facebook-like titlebar in Android

Tags: android, android-widget

I noticed some applications in Android (like Facebook, WhatsApp, Google Maps and ShopSavvy) have a similar title bar with a button or more on the right corner. I know how to implement a custom title bar, there are plenty of examples here on stack overflow, but I feel like there's a library or some kind of pattern to implement them, since their sizes, icons and separators are similar. I already have a custom bar I created myself, but I'd like it looked like these ones. Are these custom bars too? Any help?

http://www.gadgetvenue.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/08/Facebook-Android-App-300x300.jpg
http://cdn1.staztic.com/screenshots/whatsapp-messenger-97-1.jpg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The iosched app is a great reference for the Dashboard and ActionBar [UI pattern Google presented at their I/O conference in 2010](http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/android-ui-design-patterns.html).

Beside that you might also want to take a look at the GreenDroid project, an Android library project that helps you implementing those best practices UI patterns like ActionBar, QuickActions etc..It's free and available here: http://android.cyrilmottier.com/?p=240

Comment: Thank you guys! I'll watch the video you suggested.

Comment: That app looks like a great reference! I can even use their images as a basis since my project is GPLv3 :)

Answer (score 4):

It's often referred to as the Action Bar. Look in the source for the Google IO conference app and you'll find what you need in there to implement it yourself.
http://code.google.com/p/iosched/

Answer (score 1):

A more up to date answer is to use ActionBarSherlock. It's awesome, and takes out a huge amount of work for getting a great action bar going that switches to the native one on 3.0+ devices (which is really important now that 4.0 phones are coming out)